# Magento missing status in Comments History section after changing the order status programmatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I changed the order status by the following code.

```
/** Change the order status **/
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
// Set user admin session
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);
const STATE_PROCESSING = 'closed';

echo $order_status = 'cancelled';
echo "<br/>";

echo $orderId=10000007;
echo "<br/>";

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
//$order->setState($order_status, true);
//$order->setState(constant($order_status), true);
$order->setData('state', $order_status);
$order->setStatus($order_status);

$order->save();
```

The order stats was changed successfully, but when I visited the view order page, the status dropdown of the comments history section was blank.
previously it shows the status like pending,compelete,processing,etc.

please give some suggestions.
Thank you in advance.
[image: image showing the dropdown of comments history section]

Answer (score 1):

```
//Status Updated start here
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

$orderId=10000007;

umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
/*
##Magento Status List
const STATE_NEW             = 'new';
const STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT = 'pending_payment';
const STATE_PROCESSING      = 'processing';
const STATE_COMPLETE        = 'complete';
const STATE_CLOSED          = 'closed';
const STATE_CANCELED        = 'canceled';
const STATE_HOLDED          = 'holded';
const STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW  = 'payment_review';
*/

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementID($orderId);
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion. In my case I discovered that there was a plugin named **custom order status** which was installed, due to which when I was setting the status the drop down I highlighted was showing no options.

Finally I got solution by using SOAP API.